# need help figuring out how to put a 'q' quit into my program

Tags: java

this is what i have so far, but when i input q it gives me lines of text that are not my desired out put of "Q"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DollarsandCents
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "q";
    double currency; 

    System.out.println("Enter a currency value or enter q to quit:");
    currency = stdIn.nextDouble ();

    if (currency >= .00)
    {
      System.out.printf("Formatted currency value: $%,.2f\n", currency);
    }
    else 
    {
      System.out.print("Q");
    }
  } // end main
} // end class DollarsandCents
```

what do i need to add that would be make it work?

Comment: i dont think thats the right way to compare Double values. see my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Currency 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      String currencyValue="";
      while (true)
      {
          System.out.print("Enter a currency value or enter q to quit: ");
          currencyValue = stdIn.nextLine();
          if(currencyValue.equals("q")) {
              System.out.println("You pressed q, have a nice day");
              break;
          }
          System.out.printf("Formatted currency value: $%,.2f\n", Double.parseDouble(currencyValue));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In your `while` condition you are checking `!currencyValue.equals("q")` and in your `if` you are checking `currencyValue.equals("q")`. arent they contradicting to each other ?

Comment: i dont think we need a loop

Comment: @Rehman on the line above, we are changing `currencyValue` so in order to leave the loop, i've put it there.

Comment: @Sekula1991 Anyways you are breaking the loop. So `true` will be fine i guess in the while condition.

Comment: i think you also need to check for >=0.00 condition

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "q";
    double currency; 

    System.out.println("Enter a currency value or enter q to quit:");
    currency = stdIn.nextLine ();

    if (currency.equals(q))
    {
      System.out.print("Q");

    }
    else 
    {
      double curr =  Double.parseDouble(currencyValue);
      if( Double.compare(curr,0.00) >= 0)
      {
          System.out.printf("Formatted currency value: $%,.2f\n", curr);
      }

      else 
           System.out.printf("Currency value is less than 0.00");

    }
  } // end main
```